# How can I block a specific host

Tags: linux

I am not good with linux. I need to know 3 ways to block HTTP service on port 80 for a specific host on my machine. I need 3 commands or tools. I have looked everywhere and all I can find is the command to block HTTP service by the IP tables.  Please help, even if you can point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What linux distro/version are you using?  You probably want iptables entries, but that is difficult to say without knowing specifics on your host.

Comment: it is a general question.  I used the IP table configuration: shin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -- destination port 80 -j DROP, I think that would be one way, but I have no idea about any other commands or tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HTTP connections are translated on the client, before asking your DNS server, using a `hosts` file.
Here you can list a specific host name and use the shortcut of your local machine `127.0.0.1`. Thus, that address is effective not resolved, and the resource will typically return a `404` error (unless you are running a local webserver with a similar path).
It's not considered the best solution, but a very simple common solution.
The host file is located at `/etc/hosts`. Its a text file that you can edit. Research for more detailed info and syntax.

Comment: If no webserver is running on port 80, a connection refused is returned. Not a 404 error.